# remediation script for centos 7 throws syntax errors

Tags: openscap

thanks in advance.  i am running a fresh download of openscap on centos7 (patched).  it produces a remediation script, but the script throws an error repeatedly.  its the same syntax issue many times in the script

```
./x.sh: line 107: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./x.sh: line 107: `     readarray -t matches < <(sed -s -n -e "\;${pattern};!d" -e "/${arch}/!d" -e "/${group}/!d;F" /etc/audit/rules.d/*.rules)'
```

it seems not to like the `matches < <(sed` portion.

can anyone help me out and let me know what i need to change to make this portion of the script work?

thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your shell doesn't support [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Some shells don't support this, eg. plain `sh` throws this error. It should work with Bash. Try to run the script as `bash x.sh`. If that doesn't help, check also if Bash isn't run in [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html).

Comment: that did it, i ran the script with bash and it worked...thanks again!